# Nav list extends beyond the wrapper. How to create a dropdown for extra items?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a `nav` with a list of `a` links extending horizontally across the page. The width of the area is limited, but the links are still extending past the max width (the border is the area):
[image]

I want any "extra" items (in this case, the last two items) to be in a dropdown menu just like the one in developer tools:
[image]

Between HTML & CSS/SCSS, how would I go about accomplishing this?

Here's my HTML:

```html
<header class="doc-header">
  <div class="wrapper wrapper-border">
      <nav class="doc-nav">
        <a class="doc-page-link" href="yahoo.com">Ansible</a>
        <a class="doc-page-link" href="google.com">PowerShell</a>
      </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

SCSS:

```scss
.wrapper {
  max-width: calc(#{$content-width} - (#{$spacing-unit}));
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: $spacing-unit * .5;
  padding-left: $spacing-unit * .5;
  @extend %clearfix;

  @media screen and (min-width: $on-large) {
    max-width: calc(#{$content-width} - (#{$spacing-unit} * 2));
    padding-right: $spacing-unit;
    padding-left: $spacing-unit;
  }
}
.wrapper-border {
    border: 1px solid $border-color-01;
    border-top: none;
}

.doc-nav {
    position: static;
    float: left;
    top: 9px;
    left: $spacing-unit * .5;
    background-color: inherit;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;

    .doc-page-link {
        color: $text-color;
        line-height: $base-line-height;
        display: inline;
        padding: 0;

        &:not(:last-child) {
            margin-right: 20px;
        }
        margin-left: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't achieve this with HTML + (S)CSS alone. Here's how it is achieved: you create a hidden container inside the parent and render all children inside of it to measure them. After you have their box dimensions, you need a JavaScript function  which marks items as included/excluded in the dropdown every time the parent width changes. Now you have all the information needed to render the actual items.